# Validate jQuery Mutiselect Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, multi-select

I'm using this jQuery multiselect plugin in a form and no idea how to validate whether any option is selected from it.
https://github.com/nobleclem/jQuery-MultiSelect

This is how I tried to do it but it doesn't work.

HTML

```
<select multiple id="selectbox">
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2"></option>
    <option value="3"></option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="validate" id="btn"/>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select[multiple]').multiselect();

    $('#btn').click(function(){
        if ($("#selectbox option:selected").length == 0) {
            alert('None Selected');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your last line wants to be `})`.

Comment: `<select mutiple …` -> `<select multiple …`

Comment: Sorry it was a typing mistake while typing in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is the mistake in select box `multiple`. try this,

```
<select id="selectbox" multiple>
    <option value="1">1 option</option>
    <option value="2">2 option</option>
    <option value="3">3 option</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select[multiple]').multiselect();
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        if ($('#selectbox').val() != null && $('#selectbox').val().length > 0) {
            console.log('Selected');
        }else{
            console.log('Non Selected');
        }
    });
});
```